# Using DataTables, I'm grabbing HTML strings from an API, but the table cell is displaying "<p>Hello</p>" instead of just "Hello" in a p tag. What do?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, datatables

I have tried encoding the HTML in my API, but then it just displays "<p>Hello" etc in the cell. I've also tried different variations of Html.Raw and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in the columns section of the DataTables initializer but it's possible I'm using those incorrectly. I am open to stripping HTML with replace functions if necessary (though keeping the paragraph breaks at least would be ideal), but I have used DataTables to manually render anchor tags in the cell so I don't understand how this is different. How do I tell DataTables "this is not a string, it is HTML and you should render it as such?"

Comment: Sorry, in the first line of this post, I was trying to use the &lt/&gt symbols but they were automatically read.

Comment: Do you have a minimally reproducible example of the issue? What are you using to set the content of the calls?

Comment: @asyncawait is right, we need you to provide an example of your code so that we know what you're working with.

Comment: See [mre] for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Didn't realize some of the data I had was already encoded, so I had to decode the affected fields before creating the JSON with them. Attempting to decode in the datatables initialization did not work. I used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(fieldName) in the API Controller, created the JSON using the decoded items, then everything worked as expected. Hope this helps someone someday.